# argparse with a pair of floats

Tags: python, argparse

Is there an elegant way to introduce a pair of floats using argparse?

I know I can use both separately and later process them to convert them into a numpy array of two floats, or even I have been suggested to enter the pair as a string and convert them to numbers but both seem ugly and unnecessary.

Is there a way to introduce a pair of floats so as later have them as a numpy array?

#### First way

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process two float numbers.')
    
    # Define two float arguments
    parser.add_argument('--number1', type=float, help='Enter the first float number')
    parser.add_argument('--number2', type=float, help='Enter the second float number')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # Check if both arguments are provided
    if args.number1 is not None and args.number2 is not None:
        # Create a numpy array
        result_array = np.array([args.number1, args.number2])
        
        return result_array
    else:
        # Handle the case when one or both arguments are not provided
        print("Please provide both float numbers.")
        return None
```

#### Second way

```
def parse_arguments():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process two float numbers.')
    
    # Define an argument for two float numbers separated by a comma
    parser.add_argument('--float_numbers', type=str, help='Enter two float numbers separated by a comma (e.g., 1.0,2.5)')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    # Check if the argument is provided
    if args.float_numbers is not None:
        # Split the string into two floats
        numbers = [float(x) for x in args.float_numbers.split(',')]
        
        # Create a numpy array
        result_array = np.array(numbers)
        
        return result_array
    else:
        # Handle the case when the argument is not provided
        print("Please provide two float numbers.")
        return None
```

Comment: Could you show the "ugly and unnecessary" ways? I'm not seeing the problem with the first option, though the second doesn't sound ideal.

Comment: @wjandrea I did. Ideally I want to call `python script.py --myparam (3.4,4.3)` or `python script.py --myparam 3.2 4.3`.  I know there is a way, I did it sometime in the past, I just can't find it

Comment: FWIW, if the numbers are *required* input, mark them as such in the argparser/make them positional arguments; don't manually check after the fact what argparser is designed to do for you.

Comment: @KansaiRobot Why did you make them optional if they're required? They should be positional instead. Or are you looking for [Argparse with two values for one argument](/q/34988908/4518341)? (Which I answered myself :)

Comment: `parser.add_argument('--myparam', nargs=2, type=float, help='two float numbers')`.  `args.myparam` should then be a list of numbers, e.g. `[3.2, 4.3]`)